# Will GetPath() work for this?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I basically want to get the outline for a character. I was wondering how I could do this without drawing to the DC. Could I do something like this: (Psudocodeishly)

BeginPath()

TextOut("H")

EndPath()

GetPath()

Will something like this work for GetPath? Will it return the glyph outline that I can then draw?

Otherwise, how else could I do this (without freetype)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get a glyph outline, why not just use [`GetGlyphOutline`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144891%28VS.85%29.aspx)? There's the theoretical limitation that this is limited to TrueType fonts, but given the percentage of other fonts typically used on Windows, that's rarely a concern...

Edit: Yes, if you want to avoid using `GetGlyphOutline`, using a path instead will work (though only with TrueType fonts, not bitmapped fonts). The sample code included with the documentation for [`CDC::BeginPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8ezcwxf%28VS.71%29.aspx) shows how to do exactly what you seem to be after (though I'd strongly recommend using `std::vector` instead of `new[]` and `delete[]` as it does). One minor detail: that sample includes an implementation of `PolyDraw`. You'd only need (or want) this if you need to support ancient 16-bit versions of Windows -- all NT-based versions of Windows include it.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to use it, but I didn't know how to use it and also it uses POINTFX which is weird. Does my method work?

Thanks